# Use double quotes as field separator in AWK

Tags: awk

How can I use double quotes as a field separator?

```
awk -v val=$num 'BEGIN { FS='"';}{}'
```

I am using above statement however encountered an error.

Comment: Whenever you have "encountered an error" you should include the error message.

Answer (score 15):

Two ways:

```
awk -v val=$num -F'"' '{}'

awk -v val=$num 'BEGIN { FS="\"";}{}'
```

Comment: small typo: the -f parameter should be -F